# Cannot start React Native 0.15 anymore

Tags: ios, xcode7, react-native

I have problems with newly initiated projects. When I do a init, I ger react native version 0.16.0-rc. the plugins I need does not support v0.16, so downgrade is the only option.

Downgrading to 0.15 seems ok, but running it i XCode result in build failure.

Reproducing steps:

```
react-native init AwesomeProject
cd AwesomeProject/
vi package.json
```

Change 0.16.0-rc to 0.15.0

```
npm cache clean
npm install
```

Open Xcode, click run.

I get following errors:
[image]

Anybody seen this problem before?

I am using: 
Xcode 7.1.1
OS X El Capitan 10.11.1 (15B42)
Node v5.1.0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can safely delete the `AwesomeProjectTests/AwesomeProjectTests.m` file as it's only for testing the Sample "Welcome to React Native" screen.

Edit: It should be noted that the file reference also needs to be removed from the Xcode project file. To do this all at once, in the Xcode editor, find the `AwesomeProjectTests/AwesomeProjectTests.m` file, right click it, then click "Delete". Xcode will ask, "Do you want to move “AwesomeProjectsTests.m” to the Trash, or only remove the reference to it?" You want to click "Move to Trash".

Comment: I will accept your answer, because it pointed me to the correct direction, however, simply delete the file will result in 'missing file' error. This was easily resolved by: `touch AwesomeProjectTests/AwesomeProjectTests.m`

Comment: Very true! It really needs to be removed from the Xcode project. I'll edit my answer to clarify.